# Async Web Api Controller - How to handle cancellations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm running an Owin Self hosted web Api, with typical controller like so:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("refresh/{secId}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(int))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RefreshElement(int secId)
    {
        var count = await _db.Refresh(secId);

        if (count == 0)
            return NotFound();

        return Ok(count);
    }
```

Assuming _db.Refresh() is long running (few secs) and sometimes throws an exception.

The problem i've managed to reproduce is this:

- Request hits the method, _db.Refresh gets fired off
- Request is cancelled (socket closed)

The result of _db.Refresh is no longer awaited - because I see when it returns an exception, it shows up via the TPL unobserved exception handling when the task is GCd...

Maybe because of such interactions the .net team changed the unhandled exception policy not to tear down processes (4.5 onwards i think)... so what's a good pattern out of this problem? Specifically for self hosted WebApi using OWIN - because i still log unobserved exceptions as FATAL :)

I can make _db.Refresh() take in a cancellation token, but how/when do i set a cancellation token for disconnects / cancels in self host webapi?

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps this does not fully answer your question, but I believe it answers this last part:

> I can make _db.Refresh() take in a cancellation token, but how/when do i set a cancellation token for disconnects / cancels in self host webapi?

If you add a `CancellationToken` parameter to your action method, the framework will supply one when it calls it.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("refresh/{secId}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(int))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RefreshElement(
    int secId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var count = await _db.Refresh(secId, cancellationToken);

    if (count == 0)
        return NotFound();

    return Ok(count);
}
```

Note however that there is still a small window of opportunity in which the client could disconnect before the action method exits, in which case your TPL unobserved exception will still occur.

Comment: Cancellation might occur just after the last time Refresh checks the token but before it fails. This just reduces the window of opportunity. Not a fix.

Comment: @usr I'm aware of the problem your comment and the other answer are addressing.  I have clarified which part of the question I am answering.

Comment: @usr I wonder if the framework knows to observe the Task in the case where the CancellationToken has been cancelled during the request?

Comment: You mean whether it will observe the Refresh task? The framework does not know that this task exists and it does not know that a token was passed to that method. In fact what Refresh does with the token could be anything. It could throw it away.

Comment: @usr The inner task isn't an issue, is it? If a client closes the connection to the service during the action method, the action method still runs to completion.  Even when a cancellation token is involved, it still runs to completion.  The inner task *is* observed, because the portion of the action method after the await is registered as a continuation of it.  The only unobserved task is the one returned from the action method.  When the action method completes but there is no client connection waiting on it, it completes unobserved (hence the TPL unobserved task exception).

Comment: @usr Hence all the framework would have to do is, when a client connection closes and stops waiting on the action method task while the action method is still running, it could see that the action method advertises graceful cancellation and just throw this now-orphaned task into a collection of those that need to be observed when they finish. -- I'm guessing here, and am not in a position to verify this behavior right now. :)

Comment: I think the framework should process the request as if no cancellation had happened. The app can take advantage of the token but there is little reason for the infrastructure to do so in this particular situation.

Comment: @usr Actually, why does the framework not always just observe the result of the action method, even if the client stopped listening?  That seems to be desirable behavior considering it provides a CancellationToken. Maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Well, if it observed the result and threw it away that would be suppressing errors. Suppressing errors is the same as catch {}. Someone needs to be notified if a task crashes. That's why I suggest to continue to process the request and let the normal error handling take its course.

Comment: @usr A client disconnecting during a request isn't a server error though... The framework created the task, and it should observe it.

Comment: The disconnect is benign and should be suppressed. It's the action method task that should never be suppressed.

Comment: @usr: So the long and short of your argument is "let the normal error handling take it's course" - so how does that work for a web api? Run every single task with a continuation on error for reliable error handling? or simply ignore such cases, ensure no controller can ever have a side effect on error and let the tasks keep getting GCd? Or something better? :)

Comment: @Vivek Simply await all tasks and the error bubble up. Async code usually is structurally identical to the synchronous version. The translation is mechanic: Slap await on everything and call the XxxAsync version. The same error handling system that non-async web frameworks use applies here as well.

Comment: @usr - slightly different i think. If this was a fully synchronous call, a thread abort by the web api would reach into the _db.Refresh() and stop it midway/wherever it could (which is another can of worms), but is different behavior from the async setup - which lets _db.Refresh run to completion. Btw what you said is what i'm already doing in all my code - letting it bubble up.

Comment: @Vivek Thread abort is very unsafe and can never be used to abort requests. I believe ASP.NET does it sometimes which is a horrible design choice. Thread.Abort can render the entire app domain permanently unusable. If it happens to abort string.cctor for example all usages of string will fail forever.

Comment: @usr - oh i don't do abort... but web api might be, because that's the kind of behavior i'm seeing for user cancelled requests :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the request time out by implementing a middleware yourself.

The `IOwinContext` has a `Request` property which itself holds a `CancellationToken` named `CallCancelled` which can be polled to see if the request was canceled:

```
public class CancellationAwareOwinMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(IOwinContext owinContext)
    {
        try
        {
              await Next.Invoke(owinContext);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
             // Handle cancellation.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             if (owinContext.Request.CallCancelled.IsCancellationRequested)
             {
                 // Handle cancellation.
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the general exception clause is there because i'm not sure OWIN will throw a TCE when tge request is cancelled, so pole the token anyway to be sure.

**Edit:**

As @usr pointed out to me, this solution would handle the case of the outter `Task` going unobserved, and that was a rather large assumption I was making. If it's the inner task, I'll need to rethink the solution.

Comment: Does this really solve the problem that the task returned by `RefreshElement` might never be observed?

Comment: @usr The question is which `Task` is going unobserved, the inner task or the outter. But you're right, i'm not sure why I assumed it was the outter.

Comment: I think the inner task is going to be observed by the await which is still running. It's not being cancelled. In fact `RefreshElement` is never cancelled.

Comment: I agree. OWIN is only aware of the outter task. I think my brain was assuming that the inner task would still go observed by the `await` which would resume on an arbitrary thread anyway, as you said.